# Получите массив из чисел, содержащих цифру 8

Tags: javascript

Напишите функцию с именем `luckyChineseNumber`, которая принимает массив numbers в качестве аргумента и возвращает массив счастливых для китайцев чисел, т.е. чисел, содержащих цифру 8.

В решении используйте метод `string.includes(otherStr[, index]`.

Примеры:

функция `luckyChineseNumber([124, 18, 13, 8, 81, 182, 11])` должна возвратить `[18, 8, 81, 182]`.

---

Пробовал так:

```
function luckyChineseNumber(numbers) {
    let str = numbers.join(',') let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
        if (str.includes('8')) arr.push(i)
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Не понимаю как вывести элементы с цифрой 8 со строки, в массив

Comment: В чём у вас загвоздка?

Comment: использую метод includes, но не могу вывести цифры в массив. Возвращается пустой массив. Наверное, что-то неправильно делаю.

Comment: Напишите в вопросе ваш код, посмотрим-с... По идее надо предварительно число в строку перевести

Comment: function luckyChineseNumber(numbers){
let str = numbers.join(',')
let arr = [];
for(let i = 0; i <= str.length; i++){
 if(str.includes('8')) arr.push(i)
 }
 return arr;
 }

Comment: не понимаю как вывести элементы с цифрой 8 со строки, в массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас много лишних действий. Все числа не надо приводить к единой строке. Надо

1. Пробегаться циклом уже по имеющемуся массиву
2. Каждый элемент приводить к строке
3. К получившейся строке из текущего элемента применить метод `includes`

---

В итоге у вас на каждой итерации будут строки `"124"`, `"18"` и т.д. У которых можно применять метод `includes`

```js
let arr = [124, 18, 13, 8, 81, 182, 11];

function luckyChineseNumber(numbers) {
    let arr = [];
    
    for (let number of numbers)
        if (number.toString().includes('8'))     
            arr.push(number);
            
    return arr;
}

console.log(luckyChineseNumber(arr));
```

---

```js
let arr = [124, 18, 13, 8, 81, 182, 11];

const luckyChineseNumber = (numbers) => numbers.filter(number => number.toString().includes('8'));

const luckyChineseNumber2 = (stack, number) => stack.filter(el => el.toString().includes(number));
// --------------------------------------------------------

console.log(luckyChineseNumber(arr));
console.log(luckyChineseNumber2(arr, 8));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь все понятно!!!